# CSS stickied login button to the top

Tags: css, button

I want to make something like this:

http://puu.sh/1b5jU

So I did something here, but it doesn't look the same on all screens still when its inside bootstrap container, 960px:

http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html

What it look like on friend's screen:

http://puu.sh/1b51h

This is the css for it all

```
.delogin {
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #443b28;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 51%;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.login {
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #443b28;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 51%;
right: 0px;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
.login:hover{
width: 70px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #443b28;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 51%;
top: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

#login {
float: right;
margin-right: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11px;
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  }
  #lock {
  background-image: url("../img/lock.png");
  width: 13px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 7px;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="delogin">
      <div class="login">
             <div id="lock"></div>
             <span id="login"><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is the whole HTML\CSS if needed:

http://pastebin.com/qJkA99nW

Question:

How do I stick the login button how it is now to the right side inside the 960px grid system without making the menu to move any pixel to any side? and make it fit and look a bit the same or similar on all screens, browsers?

I've never seen this kind of question or tutorial on how to make a sticky button like this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question, could you perhaps pop what you have into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I want the button to be up the contact menu item without moving the whole menu down, and to be in the same spot in all browsers or screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to your `.container`

```css
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative; /* this */
}
```

and then set the position of the button

```css
.delogin {
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
    background-color: #443B28;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 51%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* this */
    width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Yes but make the screen smaller and the button will move to the side, and it's the same for my friend, just above twitter menu now.

Comment: just checked in FF and Chrome - it stays over the "Contact"

Comment: This should work, however on http://justxp.plutohost.net/slyfiles/index.html the container is set to `position: relative *zoom: 1` - this is causing the button to move around on my screen

Comment: Nope chrome, and somehow it's fixed. 

I added float: right, moved the menu abit up and to right but your answer helped me.